# WPF - Set monitor for WindowStartupLocation

Tags: wpf, monitor

How can I do if I want to choose in which monitor the window I created will be displayed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Screen.PrimaryScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen.aspx) and/or [`Screen.AllScreens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx)  (collection) to get the location of the screen and position your window accordingly.